# Getting next value from sequence with jpa repository in postgreSQL

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I've seen the similar question, but in my situation it doesn't work.
I need to get the next value of the sequence.

Model class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "item")
public class Item {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "id_seq", sequenceName = "item_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "id_seq")
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false)
    protected Long id;
}
```

Jpa Repository:

```
public interface ItemRepository extends JpaRepository<Item, Long> {
    List<Item> findFirst10ByOrderByPublicationDateDesc();

    @Query(value = "SELECT item_id_seq.nextval FROM item", nativeQuery = 
    true)
    Long getNextSeriesId();
}
```

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I've found solution:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT nextval('item_id_seq')", nativeQuery =
            true)
    Long getNextSeriesId();
```

My mistake was that I used oracle syntax instead of postgreSQL, which I am using.